# Minimum polynomial of the $11^{\text{th}}$ root of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

Ring of polynomials = $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

I'm having a confusion with the theory of minimum polynomials.
Say is $z$ is an $11^{th}$ root of unity. (That is: $z^{11}=1$).
And I know because of the cyclotomic polynomial, we have $z^{11}-1=(z-1)(z^{10}+z^{9}+...z+1)$.
1. Hence it is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ Am I correct?
2. Hence we can say that the minimum polynomial can be of degree less than $11$. Is that correct?
3. And is there any more detail that I can obtain about the minimum polynomial of $z$?
4.And also how about the $[\mathbb{Q}[z]:\mathbb{Q}]$ (That is the dimension of the vector space adjoining $z$ to $\mathbb{Q}$)
5. Also it always gives me the doubt why z can not be equal to one... is it because the roots of unity are defined not to be equal to one? 
I really appreciate your help

Comment: the dimension is $10$ because the minimal polynomial has degree $10$

Comment: can I please know how did you obtained the minimum polynomial

Comment: Also it always gives me the doubt why $z$ can not be equal to one... can you explain that too

Comment: there are $11$ roots of $z^{11}-1$; one is $z=1$, and the others are the $\phi(11)=10$ primitive $11^{th}$ roots of $1$; cf. [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Cyclotomic_polynomials)

Comment: @gune It can. It's just that that case is uninteresting.

Comment: Thank you. So just to make it very clear, ..   
since $z\neq1$ we have $z^{10}+z^{9}+...z+1$ as the minimum polynomial of all the other $10$ elements that satisfies $z^{11}-1=0$. Hence for all those $z$, we have $[\mathbb{Q}(z):\mathbb{Q}]=10$.. Am I correct

Comment: Yes, and as pointed out by @J.W.Tanner, the irreducibility of $X^{10} + X^9 + \cdots + X + 1 = \frac{X^{11} - 1}{X - 1}$ follows from Eisenstein's criterion after substituting $X \to X + 1$ and computing $\frac{(X + 1)^{11} - 1}{X}$ with the binomial theorem and properties of $n \choose p$ for $p$ prime.

Comment: Got it Thanks alot!